# Get timeoutseconds value for a Stored Process server

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

As per [documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=biasag&docsetTarget=n16001intelplatform00srvradm.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n16024intelplatform00srvradm):

> "timeoutseconds = seconds"
>
> The TIMEOUTSECONDS parameter specifies the
>     time interval that an OLAP server or a stored process server waits
>     before it stops a client process and cleans up the server run-time
>     environment context.

My question is - how do I obtain this value programmatically, eg as part of a Stored Process?

Comment: Proc OPTIONS is one place to start. If not there the server process may have pushed the parameter value into metadata.  If in metadata you can use METABROWSE to manually locate and copy the uri, and programmatically use the URI in METADATA_GETATTR function to retrieve the value.

Comment: Was not in proc options.. I looked in metabrowse but couldn't find it!  Will keep looking.

Comment: Proc IOMOPERATE might surface the information your are looking for. Look for Chris Hemedinger [SAS blog](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=biasag&docsetTarget=n16001intelplatform00srvradm.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n16024intelplatform00srvradm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`STPSRVGETN`](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=stpug&docsetTarget=srvgetn.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)
Returns the numeric value of a server property

> ```
> SAS Statements                                             Results
> ------------------------------------------------------     ---------------------
> dsesstimeout=stpsrvgetn('default session timeout');
> put dsesstimeout=;                                         dsesstimeout=900
>
> sessmaxtimeout=stpsrvgetn('maximum session timeout');
> put sessmaxtimeout=;                                       sessmaxtimeout=3600
>
> session=stpsrvgetn('session timeout');
> put session=;                                              session=900
>
> maxconreqs=stpsrvgetn('maximum concurrent requests');
> put maxconreqs=;                                           maxconreqs=1
>
> deflrecl=stpsrvgetn('default output lrecl');
> put deflrecl=;                                             deflrecl=65535
>
> version=stpsrvgetn('version');                             
> put version=;                                              version=9.4
> ```

Comment: nice - very useful!